# Set campaign with current page view in Google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to fire Campaign name in pageview javascript GTM. 
Where this is achievable on universal GA using the following script

### Initial

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'xxx.com');
```

### Addition

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'campaignName');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'source');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'medium');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Are there anyway to achieve this with GTM using javascript? Given the initial code below:

### Initial

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxxx');
```

### Addition

??????

Answer (score 1):

**Chanon**,

you can do this easily with using *Fields to set* section (part of any Google/Universal Analytics tag template):

[image]

Here you can find the [overview of all fields accessible](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference).

Comment: Can you explain this plz .. I have installed google tag manager to my site but it doesnt tracking my campaign mail links

Comment: Sameera, can you pleas start a new question with more details and specifics for your tracking setup?